Too many open files in system AH02179
Our site running on apache and it is a WordPress site. Recently, we tried to switch its domain amidst the switching process we encountered a 502 error
Upon consulting the log, it was mentioned that "Too many open files in the system" as depicted in the screenshot below.
What could've caused a number of files to be open to go higher? How can we increase the number of open files in a Debian system?
current specs
error log

You can check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182021/too-many-open-files and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-the-too-many-open-files-error-in-linux/

Thank you Vinoth, will have a look :)

Welcome to serverfault. For your next question, please try not to use pictures, but copy the part of the log file as text into your question.
